# How to filter devices in Flurry analytics?

Tags: ios, flurry-analytics

We are beginning to use Flurry analytics in our iOS applications, but the production data is polluted by emulator sessions and QA device sessions.

Is it possible to avoid that in other ways than by using separate Flurry accounts for dev/QA and production? I cannot find options to filter data in the Flurry admin console.

I have read suggestions to use an invalid key for non-release configurations, is there nothing better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a separate API key for testing/development and for the live version of the app is the best way to prevent test sessions from mixing with your live data. You can solve the problem going forward by creating a new project for future testing.

Looking backwards one way to filter out the data would be to use the time frame filters to remove the testing data from the metrics display.

If you have specific app versions that contain only testing data those can be deleted individually, but be very cautious with this approach. Version deletion is irreversible.